# How do I get a handle uintptr of a child process?

Tags: windows, go, process, handle, suspend

I want to start a child process (i'm on windows 10) and I would like to be able to suspend and resume the process at will.

I found this neat undocumented windows function `NtSuspendProcess` from `ntdll.dll` that should do the job but now I need to get the handle of the process to issue the suspend command.

this is an example:

```
modntdll = syscall.NewLazyDLL("ntdll.dll")
procNtSuspendProcess = modntdll.NewProc("NtSuspendProcess")
procNtResumeProcess  = modntdll.NewProc("NtResumeProcess")
_, _, err = procNtSuspendProcess.Call(uintptr(handle))
_, _, err = procNtResumeProcess.Call(uintptr(handle))
```

To start the process I would normally use the `exec.Command` function but I can't find a way to retrieve the handle of the process.

**Is there a way to get the handle when starting a process?**
If not with `exec.Command`, what other library should I use to start a process that returns also the process handle?

*As a side note:

I've looked into `syscall.StartProcess` but it's quite low level and I don't feel able to handle such a raw implementation.*

```
_, handle, err := syscall.StartProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", []string{}, procAttr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go does not publicly expose the handle in `exec.Command`, you will have to access it either by.

Reflection

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe")
cmd.Start()
handle := uintptr(reflect.ValueOf(cmd.Process).Elem().FieldByName("handle").Uint())
```

or by creating an identical Process type and casting the Cmd.Process to your own type to access the private fields.

```
type Process struct {
   Pid int
   handle uintptr
   isdone uint32
   sigMu sync.RWMutex
}
```

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe")
cmd.Start()
proc := (*Process)(unsafe.Pointer(cmd.Process))
println(proc.handle)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
If you had to choose between one of the 2 methods, which is the best? safest? most efficient?

Comment: What are the possible pros and cons/drawbacks of the 2 methods?

Comment: Reflection is slower, it'll break if they rename it from handle to something else (highly doubt that). I don't like using reflection (a personal choice), in any of my own code. The pointer casting is completely valid under the spec provided that what you are casting to is no larger than what you are casting from (memory wise) and that the two share an equivalent memory layout. It'll break if they decide to add a field in between the Pid & handle (again highly doubt). I've seen a few other projects do this trick, so if it does happen, you are not alone.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the explanation, in case the `os.Process` struct should be modified, I would just need to modify my own declaration of the `Process` struct (mirroring the original struct) right?

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67918922/12336465) by "Make that 4" were both flawless, being simple and well explained.

I would just add an additional method that I found, just for completeness (requires the import of `golang.org/x/sys/windows`)
*Update: apparently this method might lead to bugs/errors and it's probably better not to implement it (check the comments)*

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd.exe")
cmd.Start()

// using PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME since I want to call NtSuspendProcess function
handle, _ := windows.OpenProcess(windows.PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME, false, uint32(cmd.Process.Pid))
defer windows.CloseHandle(handle)

fmt.Println(handle)
```

Comment: There is a race condition here, as PIDs can be reused (they don't have a lifetime separate from the process itself, like a HANDLE does)

Comment: Also in your answer, the HANDLE value is no longer meaningful at the time you printed it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll leave this answer for clarity and I'll reference your comments in it

Comment: @BenVoigt what about the answer by "Make that 4" ? Does it also have the same problem?